# how to add voice search in search view

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I've Created search view in my app and now i want to add voice search on that how i do that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8My0.jpg)
this is the image
in this search view is available i want to add voice search in it

This is code for Activity_main.xml in it search view is created now want to add voice search in  which the result of voice search have to display on search box

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/custom_font"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="302dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="12.1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_view_design"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contextClickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
                app:queryHint="Type Word..">



            </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>




        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty_history"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:visibility="visible">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Search History Here.."
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#313131"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_history"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActicity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolBar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchView.onActionViewExpanded();

            }
    });
        mdatabase = new Databasehelper(this);
        if(mdatabase.checkDatabase())
        {
            openDatabase();
        }
        else
        {
            LoadDatabase ld = new LoadDatabase(this);
            ld.execute();
        }

        final String[] from = new String[] {"en_word"};
        final int[] to  = new int[]{R.id.suggestion_text};
        suggestionadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.suggestion_row,null,from,to,0)
        {
            @Override
            public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
                super.swapCursor(cursor);
                }
        };
        searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionadapter);
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int i) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int i) {
                CursorAdapter ca = searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter();
                Cursor cursor = ca.getCursor();
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                String clicked_word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("en_word"));
                searchView.setQuery(clicked_word,false);
                searchView.clearFocus();
                searchView.setFocusable(false);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Word_meaningActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("en_word",clicked_word);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    String text = searchView.getQuery().toString().replaceAll("\\s+","");
                    Pattern P = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z \\-.]{1,25}");
                    Matcher m = P.matcher(text);
                if(m.matches()) {
                    Cursor c = mdatabase.getmeaning(text);
                    if (c.getCount() == 0) {

                        showDialog();
                    } else {
                        searchView.clearFocus();
                        searchView.setFocusable(false);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Word_meaningActivity.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("en_word", text);
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                else{
                    showDialog();
                }

                return false;
            }
```

**can Anyone help me in that**

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Dont forget the permission: `Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`

You can create an Speech intent to capture the voice and then recall the speech back via `onActivityResult`

Create an intent

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
           intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak to search");
        try {
           startActivityForResult(intent, 123456);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
           //show toast?
        }
     }
```

And then within the onActivityResult, capture the speech and pass it to your search.

```
@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      switch (requestCode) {
         case 123456: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
               ArrayList result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
               textView.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
         }
      }
   }
```

The android documentation can be found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer

Comment: in this result will go on textview i want that in searchview because there is only one field that is searchview

Comment: Then change `textView.setText(result.get(0));` and pass it to your search view.